# Accessing JSON with Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am currently developing an app and I want to display some information about a particular place. I am using Google Places API to do this and am trying to extract some information from this JSON response:

```
{
"html_attributions": [],
"result": {
"address_components": [],
"adr_address": "5, \u003cspan class=\"street-address\"\u003e48 Pirrama Rd\u003c/span\u003e, \u003cspan class=\"locality\"\u003ePyrmont\u003c/span\u003e \u003cspan class=\"region\"\u003eNSW\u003c/span\u003e \u003cspan class=\"postal-code\"\u003e2009\u003c/span\u003e, \u003cspan class=\"country-name\"\u003eAustralia\u003c/span\u003e",
"formatted_address": "5, 48 Pirrama Rd, Pyrmont NSW 2009, Australia",
"formatted_phone_number": "(02) 9374 4000",
"geometry": {},
"icon": "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
"id": "4f89212bf76dde31f092cfc14d7506555d85b5c7",
"international_phone_number": "+61 2 9374 4000",
"name": "Google",
"photos": [],
"place_id": "ChIJN1t_tDeuEmsRUsoyG83frY4",
"rating": 4.5,
"reference": "CmRaAAAAVvEJLOszIgZMqrn59xg_wEmLJUpC52Zd7HZzzcv0OsaRobY_f8galxBVNsyEgC9nhUsI7BQQcTYCA0t_f8JlhEV-dftt-OhapkRRvQ12g6R3FU-d6OWB-T1vYVIcRuEBEhBha4swICH7pUUsjBRivnHTGhT1Y97NAmr0iWe4qffGJH0iY96GKg",
"reviews": [],
"scope": "GOOGLE",
"types": [
  "point_of_interest",
  "establishment"
],
"url": "https://maps.google.com/?cid=10281119596374313554",
"user_ratings_total": 133,
"utc_offset": 660,
"vicinity": "5 48 Pirrama Road, Pyrmont",
"website": "https://www.google.com.au/about/careers/locations/sydney/"
},
"status": "OK"
}
```

The code I am using in my view controller is:

```
let reposURL = NSURL(string: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=\(chosenPlaceID!)&key=SOMEAPIKEY")!

    if let JSONData = NSData(contentsOfURL: reposURL) {

        if let json = (try? NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(JSONData, options: [])) as? NSDictionary {

            if let reposArray = json["result"] as? [NSDictionary] {

                for item in reposArray {
                    placeRepositories.append(PlaceRepository(json: item ))
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

The code in my placeRepository controller is:

```
class PlaceRepository {

var name: String?
var formattedAddress: String?
var formattedPhoneNumber: String?
var internationPhoneNumber: String?
var types: [String]?

init(json: NSDictionary) {
    self.name = json["name"] as? String
    self.formattedAddress = json["formatted_address"] as? String
    self.formattedPhoneNumber = json["formatted_phone_number"] as? String
    self.internationPhoneNumber = json["international_phone_number"] as? String
    self.types = json["types"] as? [String]

    }
}
```

**`I have put a breakpoint in to try and find out what is going on and the for item in reposArray code is never accessed, it gets skipped over in the previous if statement but I am not sure why?`** Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your response suggests json["result"] is not array of dictionary ... `[NSDictionary]`  ... its `NSDictionary`

change this line

```
if let reposArray = json["result"] as? [NSDictionary] { ... }
```

with

```
if let reposArray = json["result"] as? NSDictionary {
      PlaceRepository(json: reposArray )
}
```

> After that you can't loop NSDictionary like
>         `for item in reposArray { .. }`

Comment: Now I get an error on the line: `placeRepositories.append(PlaceRepository(json: item ))` which says - cannot convert value of type 'Element' (aka '(key: AnyObject, value: AnyObject)') to expected argument type 'NSDictionary'

Comment: When I run that it doesn't give me any errors now but how would I access the values? I tried to do `print(placeRepositories.name)` but it says Value of type [PlaceRepository] has no member 'name'

Comment: Oh sorry I forgot to include this bit in my code. At the top of the view controller class I have declared a variable `var placeRepositories = [PlaceRepository]()` I have then altered the code as you suggested but put this line `placeRepositories.append(PlaceRepository(json: reposArray ))` so when I tried to print I did `print(placeRepositories.name)` but it gave me the error I just mentioned

Comment: I think I understand what you are saying I am just not sure how to go about setting this up so it works in the way I need. Thank you for your help though! You have been super quick and thorough

Comment: I don't really need it to be an array then do I, because I will be sending the request and receiving information about one place then I just need to access different bits of information about that one place.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! Your explanation really helped. I have just fixed it :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use third party libraries like [SwiftyJson](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) It's make JSON parsing more easy task.